# jquery margin grid layout

Tags: jquery, grid, margin

I'm creating a responsive grid system system that uses percentages to size elements. I tried building it with floats, inline-block, and tables. I'm sure I want to stick with inline-block because it allows me to center items vertically and horizontally. I built my design without using margins. I am using the border-box model so padding and borders won't collapse the rows.

However, I'm wanting to upgrade my grid system to allow you to set margins without breaking the row. Basically a jquery custom built "box-sizing: margin-box;".

My hope is that I can use jquery to subtract the percentage width of margins from the percentage width of the containers. However, this in and of itself doesn't work well because inline-block adds extra white space. So in addition to my current plan, I am using jquery to subtract the extra white space from margin-right. I've actually gotten it working! It does what I want it to, but I'm facing a minor problem.

The calculations are not precise enough and the rows end up coming a few pixels different from each other. It means I don't get even straight lines at the end of each row. The overall rows come out to different lengths. How do I make the calculations precise enough to line up accurately?

Here is the code:

```
     boxsizing = function(container){

     jQuery(container).each(function() {
      var el = jQuery(this);

      el.css('width', '');
      el.css('margin-right', '');

      var parentWidth = el.parent().width();

      var childWidth = el.outerWidth(false);

      //finds ratio of child container to parent container
      var childDecimal = (childWidth / parentWidth);


      //converts child container to a decimal
      childDecimal = Math.round(childDecimal*10000);


      //gets font size
      var fontSize = el.css('font-size');
      //removes px from the end
      var fontSize = fontSize.slice (0, -2);
      //calculates white space on the right of each div
      var whiteSpace = 0.29*fontSize;
      var fontDecimal = whiteSpace / parentWidth;
      //converts white space to a decimal
      fontDecimal = Math.round(fontDecimal*10000)

      //subtracts extra white space from margin-right
      var newMarginRight = el.css('margin-right');
      var newMarginRight = newMarginRight.slice (0, -2);
          newMarginRight = Math.round(newMarginRight);
          newMarginRight = newMarginRight - whiteSpace;
          newMarginRight = newMarginRight / parentWidth;
          newMarginRight = Math.round(newMarginRight*10000);
          newMarginRight = newMarginRight/100;


      //finds margin to parent ratio
      var marginDecimal = (el.outerWidth(true) - childWidth)/parentWidth;
      //converts margin to decimal form
      marginDecimal = Math.round(marginDecimal*10000);

      //take previous width and subtract margin from it
      var newWidth = (childDecimal - marginDecimal)/100;

      //set the element's width to the new calcualted with and set margin right to the updated value
      el.css('width', newWidth + "%");
      el.css('margin-right', newMarginRight + "%");
     });
    }


    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        boxsizing('.margins');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

So let me get this straight, you're going to use jQuery to "fix" a grid framework? This would be a good time to gather your thoughts and go back to the drawing board.

All grid systems invariably involve compromises, some don't do so great with whitespace (inline grids), some need vestigial classes (float grids), some are just gross (table grids). But there's one thing they all agree on, **they use CSS**.

If you wanted a javascript grid, then your markup could be literally anything. You could make actual `<row>` and `<column>` elements, because who cares, you're going to just javascript hotdog it anyway. The reason nobody does this is simple, until the content has completely loaded and your scripts have sorted it all out, the browser has nothing to show the user.

Any grid system that depends on javascript (and by extension, jQuery) has to do one of two things:

1. Hide the page contents until everything is "just right" to draw it all. **OR**
2. Show a messed up page, then jerk it all around to fix it.

Neither of those options is typically considered acceptable. So feel free to design your own grid system, lord knows [the internet needs more of them](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/03/04/css-grids/), but do it with CSS.